# ajax call in jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a ajax call which i need to call with some specific parameter attached to it such that there is parameter field in net section in firebug.

and the parameter is not a data but a type like type, = copy must be attached to the call

Comment: Hi buddy, what's you question?

Comment: Please post the code and show your effort on this, state the problem as much clear as possible to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use like this and pass data..

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "example.php",
          data: { identityid:0,userid:"<?php echo $user_id;?>" },
          success: function() {       


                  }
           });
```